# laravel using policy with many to many relationship pivot table

Tags: laravel, policy

how do you set policy in many to many relationship since it is using pivot table 
||***laravel version 6***||
Example:**MainTable**[company and user] **PivotTable**[company_user]

using view policy as example:

```
 public function view(User $user,Company $company)
{
    return $user->companys()->company_id == $company->id;
}
```

**rules:** (only the user that belongs to a company can view )
**At the moment above code is not working**
i cannot find example in google or at the documentation it self since most of example is Post and User which they dont consist of pivot table ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of `pluck()` and `contains()` collection methods.

```
public function view(User $user, Company $company)
{
    return $user->companys->pluck('id')->contains($company->id);
}
```

Pluck: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck

Contains: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-contains

**Update**

Was going through my old answers and decided to make a change to this answer.

`firstWhere()` is more efficient for this task.

```
public function view(User $user, Company $company)
{
    return $user->companys->firstWhere('id', $company->id);
}
```

Comment: it is working but , returning false: 403
This action is unauthorized. to all  even if the user is a memeber of the company still returning false .